# "kpsewhich" error when trying to build from Textmate

Tags: errors, editors, textmate

I'm using LaTeX pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.9-2.2 on Mac OSX 10.6. When I try to build from TextMate (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) I get the following error:

```
Please add the directory containing “kpsewhich” to PATH in TextMate's Shell 
Variables preferences.
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you are using Textmate to run a shell?

Comment: which OS and which LaTeX distribution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open up the file `~/.bash_profile` and add the following to the end

```
PATH="/usr/texbin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This should patch the issue.

**NOTE 1**: To open the `~/.bash_profile` open terminal and type `mate ~/.bash_profile` or 
`vim ~/.bash_profile`

**NOTE 2**: The PATH could be located elsewhere for you as mentioned in one of the comments bellow

**FYI**:

- `mate` is the command line or bash call to TextMate.
- `vim` is the bash call to vim (an command line editor).
- `~` is the bash reference to your home directory.
- a `.` before a file is UNIX's (What OSX runs on) way of specifying a hidden file, which is why you can't see the .bash_profile in your home folder.

Comment: Hey Ban, How do you open up the file ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: in my case the path was at  "/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin"
so here is how I set the PATH in my .bash_profile:
                               
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin:${PATH}"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message. In my case I did the following which solved the problem :

1. Locate `kpsewhich` using `find / -name kpsewhich* -print`. 
   In my case, the `kpsewhich` executable is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin`.
2. Add the path to the `PATH` variable in TextMate. In TextMate go to Preferences... > Advanced > Shell variables. Add `:/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin`to the existing value of `PATH` variable.
3. Do <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and it worked. No need to restart anything.

Comment: I am aware that this is an old thread, but just for future reference for anyone having the same problem, this worked for me! My kpsewhich file was in exactly the same location too. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find the path where kpsewhich should be using that command. I am using Miktex. Is it possible that I don't have it?

Answer (score 4):

How about: go to 'Preferences' in TextMate, and add `/usr/texbin` to the PATH in the 'Shell Variables'? After all, that is what TextMate itself suggests ...

Comment: Adding that path directly to your bash profile makes LaTeX, TeX, etc accessible not only from TextMate, but also from Terminal or any other program that accesses programs through the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these path-setting options worked directly for me.  Not even after restarting Textmate 2.

However, I noticed that there was a little check box next to the `PATH` - the first line in Textmate - Preferences - Variables.  Checking that box immediately resolved the problem.  I had previously run

```
which kpsewhich
```

from the command prompt and added its path to both `~/.bashrc` and the `PATH` text value.  That editing that field didn't automatically check the box or ask if I wanted it checked is well just one of those things that might have been nice for the developers to have thought of as being useful.