# Can't find “kpsewhich” on PATH. Textmate+mactex

Tags: mactex, textmate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["kpsewhich" error when trying to build from Textmate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/kpsewhich-error-when-trying-to-build-from-textmate)

Most manuals I have seen on textmate claims that command+B is compiling LaTeX documents, however this command seems to just add \textbf{}. Some other manual claims that command+R is the way to compile, however this command yield the following result:

> Can't find “kpsewhich” on PATH.

What does this mean, and what is the solution?

I have downloaded textmate and mactex. I'm not sure if I need the mactex.zip. I'm new to both text mate and Mac. (Have used LaTeX on Ubuntu for 2 years, however)

Comment: Have you actually installed MacTeX as well as TextMate? If not, your problem isn't with the path, it's the fact that you haven't actually installed MacTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH environmental variable is a list of directories that your computer searches through in order to find programs to execute. You can find it by opening a terminal and typing:

`echo $PATH`

Most likely when you installed MacTeX, it did not change your PATH, and so your computer does not know what folders to look in in order to find your MacTeX executable programs ("binaries"). (`kpsewhich` is one such program).

There are different ways to change your PATH; googling it would turn up a lot. My personal preference would be to edit (or create) the file `~/.profile` (or use `~/.bash_profile` if it already exists), and add a line that looks like this:

`export PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH`

That (after a new log in) should add `/usr/texbin` to the beginning of your PATH. Note, I am not a MacTeX user, and so I'm not sure that's the right directory to add. I'm getting that from [this page in the MacTeX FAQ](http://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/#qm03). You'll want to make sure that directory contains kpsewhich and the other MacTeX programs. (For me, on texlive for Linux, they're in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux`.)

Comment: Oops, posted this before i noticed this way a duplicate thread.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear all these answers about changing paths. The GUI installer for textmate is supposed to work without any problems. Now, I've went to

Textmate>preferences>advanced>shell variable

and here i found the following PATH

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

so it should be working since /usr/texbin is in there?

Comment: PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Reboot(/log out+log in) somehow solved the problem. Sorry for taking up your time.